# Accessing a value from HTML form and storing in PHP variable

Tags: php, html, forms, http-post

I am trying to access a value from an HTML form, but it is not getting imported correctly.
I am getting an error stating

> undefined symbol $numb

(am trying to store my text input to `$numb`).

```php
<html>
<body>
    <?php
        if (isset($_POST['submit'])) $numb=$_POST['text'];

        if($numb<1) {
            echo "Number < 1"; 
        }
        else if (100<$numb) {
            echo "Number > 100";
        }
        else if($numb==2) {
            echo "Prime";
        }
        else if($numb%2==0) {
            echo "Not prime";
        }
        else {
            $flag=0;
        }

        for($count=3;$count<sqrt($numb);$count=$count+2) {
            if($num%$count==0) {
                $flag=1;
            }
            break;
        }
        if($flag==0) {
            echo "Not Prime";
        }
        else {
            echo "Prime";
        }
    ?>
    <form method="post" action="main.php">
        <input type="text" name="text"> <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit">
    </form>
</body>
```

Comment: can you paste your code? like how are you sending data using HTML form?  and receiving data using php?

Comment: yes 

<html>
<body>
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
$numb=$_POST['text'];  
}
/*

*/
?>
<form method="post" action="main.php">
<input type="text" name="text"> 
<input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>

Comment: I am getting error stating $numb is undefined  in the line { $numb=$_POST['text']; }

Comment: I tried the above code. Didn't see the same error. Is this the exact code that has the error? If you have modified the code, can you show us more of your code?

Comment: <html>
<body>
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit']))

$numb=$_POST['text'];   
if($numb<1)
{
echo "Number < 1";
}
else if(100<$numb)
{
echo "Number > 100";
}

else if($numb==2)
{
echo "Prime";    
} 
else if($numb%2==0)
{
echo "Not prime";  
}
else 
$flag=0;
for($count=3;$count<sqrt($numb);$count=$count+2)
{
if($num%$count==0)
{
$flag=1;
}
break;
}
if($flag==0)
{
echo "Not Prime";
}
else
{
echo "Prime";
}
?>
<form method="post" action="main.php">
<input type="text" name="text"> 
<input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>

Comment: I am getting error for $flag as well .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tried you code. The problem started here:

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) $numb=$_POST['text'];
```

If the variable `$_POST['submit']` is not set, the variable `$numb` is not initialized. Therefore using it afterwards (i.e. the `if($numb<1)` statement) will result in `Undefined variable: numb`.

Similar issue with `$flag`.

I see no reason why to run the print text if no form is submitted. Maybe you should rewrite it like this:

```
<html>
<body>
<?php

if (isset($_REQUEST['text'])) {
  $numb=$_REQUEST['text'];

  $flag=0; // initialize $flag to prevent error
  if($numb<1) {
    echo "Number < 1";
  } else if (100<$numb) {
    echo "Number > 100";
  } else if($numb==2) {
    echo "Prime";
  } else if($numb%2==0) {
    echo "Not Prime";
  } else {
    for($count=3;$count<sqrt($numb);$count=$count+2) {
      if($numb%$count==0) {
        $flag=1;
        break;
      }
    }
    if($flag==1) {
      echo "Not Prime";
    } else {
      echo "Prime";
    }
  }
}

?>
<form method="post" action="main.php">
  <input type="text" name="text"> <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you able to check number is prime or not ? I am not getting any echo or anything .

Comment: Did you submit the form?

Comment: yes . Please help me with a code that will give me the output that I am looking for . That is if I enter a number in the box and click submit , it should return whether the number is prime or not . I am checking for number between 1 to 100

Comment: Please check the code again. With the current logic, you need to submit the form for each number to check the result.

Comment: Suppose I am entering number 5 in text box and clicking submit . I should get output as Prime . 
Please note that I am not trying to print all prime numbers between 1 and 100 .

Comment: Just changed. You can see the final code here. Note: You can only learn if you do the homework yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Whatever input elements you mention in your form are posted to server (php in your case) in the form of key-value pair. Where the name attribute of your input tag becomes the key and value tag of your input element becomes the value.

```
<?php 

    if(isset($_POST['submit'])) // this will always return false. there is no input named submit in your form 
    { 

        $numb=$_POST['text']; //this will never get initialized, $numb will be always undefined

    } 

?>
```

This is correct way to check

```
<?php 

    if(isset($_POST['text'])) 
    { 

        $numb=$_POST['text']; 

    } 

?>
```

this should work

Comment: I am getting undefined symbol error not on  
        $numb=$_POST['text'];

I am getting error when I am trying to access it . Please Ref my full code above .

Comment: yes to get value of $_POST['text'] you need to check if $_POST['text'] is set or not.. `if(isset($_POST['submit']))` this will always return false